# send Post request to PHP Server

Tags: ios, afnetworking

I tried so send some data from two textfields with my button, once i press the button I receive an E-mail without the content of the textfields which I typed in my iOS Simulator. I can not find the problem, please help me.

ViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController
{
    UITextField * firstname;
    UITextField *lastname;
    UIButton *sendPost;
}
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *firstname;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *lastname;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *postButtonTapped;


-(IBAction)postButtonTapped:(id)sender;


@end
```

ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize firstname;
@synthesize lastname;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (IBAction)postButtonTapped:(id)sender
{
    NSString *myRequestString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"firstname=%@&lastname=%@",firstname.text,lastname.text];
    NSData *myRequestData = [NSData dataWithBytes: [myRequestString UTF8String] length: [myRequestString length]];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL: [NSURL URLWithString: @"http://textfake.com/test/mail.php"]];

    [request setHTTPMethod: @"POST"];
    [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"content-type"];
    [request setHTTPBody: myRequestData];

    NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest: request returningResponse: nil error: nil];
    NSString *response = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:[returnData bytes] length:[returnData length] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSLog(@"%@",response);
}

- (void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [self.firstname resignFirstResponder];
    [self.lastname resignFirstResponder];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}
```

PHP Code

```
<?php
header("Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8");
$firstname = $_POST["firstname"];
$lastname = $_POST["lastname"];
$text = "not set";
if(!empty($_POST["text"])){
    $text = $_POST["text"];
}
$lat = $_POST["lat"];
$lon = $_POST["lon"];
$dieMessage =$firstname." ".$lastname."\n".$text."\n";
$dieMessage .="Lat:".$lat."\n";
$dieMessage .="Lon:".$lon;
mail("fortesing@gmail.com", "gps daten", $dieMessage);
//echo 'Email abgeschickt!';
echo $dieMessage;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

[AFNetworking 2.0](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking)

```
- (IBAction)postButtonTapped:(id)sender
{
    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    NSDictionary *params = @{@"firstname": firstname.text,
                             @"lastname": lastname.text};
    [manager POST:@"http://textfake.com/test/mail.php" parameters:params success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    }];
}
```

Hope this works.

Answer (score 0):

for the iOS part, try this :

```
- (IBAction)postButtonTapped:(id)sender {
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://textfake.com/test/mail.php"];
    NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"firstname=%@&lastname=%@",firstname.text,lastname.text];

    NSMutableURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    // set POST method
    [urlRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    // adding keys with values
    NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
    NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[postData length]];
    [urlRequest addValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [urlRequest setHTTPBody:postData];

    NSURLSession *urlSession = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration ephemeralSessionConfiguration]];

    NSURLSessionDownloadTask *urlSessionDownloadTask = [urlSession downloadTaskWithRequest:urlRequest completionHandler:^(NSURL *localfile, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {

        NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:localfile];
        //do what you want with your data here. PS your are not on main thread !
    }];
    [urlSessionDownloadTask resume];
}
```

For the PHP part, you could not get **text, lat, lon**  as you never post it !

Comment: is it necessary to have text lat lon to be able to send firstname and lastname?

Comment: hi, its still not working, i dont get any content. 
Can you explain me for what the line NSData * data..., is?
and what i should put into it?

Comment: No, it's not mandatory to send text, lat, lon. NSData *data is the return value from the server - i.e. : when you are on the web and fill a form then press "send" button, the server is sending back or the same page or a new page (like congratulation your authentification succeed !)...

Comment: in data you'll have your echo $dieMessage; value. May be you can just NSString* newStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]; to have it as string.

Comment: did you have an error message, or just you don't receive your data in your server ?

Comment: but the server does not receive the content of my textfields for some reason.. i have this problem for 1 week.. pls help someone.

Comment: Are you sure about this : firstname.text,lastname.text ? try this self.firstname.text, self.lastname.text, and be sure to have it a iBoutlet linked from your StoryBoard. If you want to perform a quick test, just replace firstname.text,lastname.text with @"firstName", @"lastName" and check if your server receive this value...

Comment: I've test it on my PHP server. it work fine. Try to call http://textfake.com/test/mail.php from safari the page is unknown ! you have to solve this first (may be upper/lower cases)

Comment: that was not the real server adress, but my code works on yours?

Comment: yes it work (I've send @"firs name"...) and the answer is : `firstname.text lastname.text
not set
Lat:
Lon:`

Comment: yea thats exactly what i get too, but i want to get the text i typed into the textfields on my ios simulator.

Comment: You have an issue with the link between your textfields and your iBoutlets ! Don't forget to put self.firstname.text, and delete the 3 lines in your .h between { and } + remove @synthesize lines in your .m no more used if you use xcode5

Comment: ok i deleted the 3 lines in .h and the synthesizes. and have self.firstname, self.lastname. but i still dont get the text which i type into the fields when i simulate an iphone.

Comment: Did you check if you've link it to your properties (iBoutlets) ? open your storyboard and select your textfield. go to menu View / Utilities / Show Connections Inspector. now check if in connection inspector panel (right) / referencing outlet you have a link to your viewController.

Comment: try `- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.firstname.text=@"test !";
}`

Comment: with this code i should be able to get the content of the textfields which i type in the ios simulator and sent them to my server right?

Comment: no, this will put a default value in your textfield. Did you see this value (in the simulator) ?

Comment: ok now when my view loads, in my first textfield there is "test".

Comment: yes this is what it should do. Did you change to this : `NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"firstname=%@&lastname=%@",self.firstname.text,self.lastname.text];` ? can you set a breakpoint just after this place and debug to what you have in post variable ?

Comment: i solved the problem... it is because i had no wwww. before my adress -.-,what would be an easy way to send my latitude and longtitude to the server by pressing the button too.? :/

Comment: really thx for your time and attention.
is there an easy way to add the current long and lat into the post request?

Comment: like you've done for firstname and lastname... check for CLLocation exemple to get current location.

Comment: but im not allowed to use a textfield or label for lat and lon, they should just be sent when i press the button.

Comment: If the user know this information, of course you can ! CLLocation use GSM/WIFI/GPS to give the current location, or use an address to give this address location. No more no less.

Comment: actually what i mean is, i have declared 2 string latitude and longtitude in my Viewcontroller.h and added them in my post params.
but how can i make my strings latitude and longtitude get my current latitude and longtitue?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem, seems like it had some problems with:

```
[NSURL URLWithString: @"http://textfake.com/test/mail.php"]];
```

and it should be with www. instead:

```
[NSURL URLWithString: @"http://www.textfake.com/test/mail.php"]];
```