# Problems posting from iOS to php

Tags: php, ios, objective-c

I am new to objective C and php so apologies if this is a stupid question. 
I am having trouble with an app that retrieves text from textfields and posts the text onto a php file. The problem is that the variable called response that retrieves the results from the php file only displays the text from the email textfield in NSLog and none of the others.

Ive spent the last three days trying to find the solution to the problem myself but have made no progress so I think I need some outside help.

This is the code I managed to scrape together from various sources online
Xcode:

```
// Create your request string with parameter names as defined in PHP file
NSString *myRequestString = [NSStringstringWithFormat:@"surname=%@&forename=%@&address=%@&email=%@",tfSurname.text,tfForename.text,tfAddress.text,tfEmail.text];
// Create Data from request
NSData *myRequestData = [NSData dataWithBytes: [myRequestString UTF8String] length: [myRequestString length]];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:
[NSURL URLWithString: @"http://www.website.com/abc.php"]];
// set Request Type
[request setHTTPMethod: @"POST"];
// Set content-type
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"content-type"];
// Set Request Body
[request setHTTPBody: myRequestData];
// Now send a request and get Response
NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest: request returningResponse: nil error: nil];
// Log Response
NSString *response = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:[returnData bytes] length:[returnData length] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"%@",response);
```

php:

```
<?php
$surname =$_POST[‘surname’];
$forename =$_POST[‘forename’];
$address =$_POST[‘address’];
$email =$_POST['email'];
echo $surname, $forename, $address, $email;
?>
```

Comment: have a look [here][1]. The same issue have been solved


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22302493/send-post-request-to-php-server/22303089#22303089

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did everything correct but observe the quotes in post variable. While accessing email you are using the correct quotes and for others it's wrong.

```
<?php
$surname =$_POST['surname'];
$forename =$_POST['forename'];
$address =$_POST['address'];
$email =$_POST['email'];
echo $surname, $forename, $address, $email;
?>
```

Comment: That was it. I can't believe it was something so stupid causing all the problems Thank you so much for pointing it out.